# Finding MLE when there's constraint that parameters sum to 1

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multinomial-distribution

In a total population of $n$, we have $k$ types of people, with $n_1, \dots, n_k$ of them in each corresponding group. The probability of a person belonging in a group is $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_k$, $\sum_i \theta_i = 1$. Find the MLE of $\theta_i$.

I know how to do this by taking partial derivative with each individual $\theta_i$ and impose the "sum to 1" constraint by subsitute $\theta_k = 1 - \sum \theta_i$ in the objective function (more details on this solution coming).

However, I wonder if there's a way to write the likelihood function and solve the optimization problem treating $\Theta$ as a vector?

EDIT: As promised, how to solve this problem treating $\theta_i$ individually.

$$log L = n_1log(\theta_1) + \dots + n_klog(\theta_k) = n_1log(\theta_1) + \dots + n_klog(1-\sum\theta_i) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i} = \frac{n_i}{\theta_i} - \frac{n_k}{\theta_k} = 0 \\
\frac{n_i}{\theta_i} = \frac{n_k}{\theta_k} = \alpha, \forall i$$

So $\sum \theta_i = \frac{\sum n_i}{\alpha} = \frac{n}{\alpha} =1$, thus $\alpha = n$ and $\theta_1 = \frac{n_i}{n}$

Comment: Hint: [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "treating $\Theta$ as a vector"?  By taking partial derivatives you already do that.

Comment: @whuber I don't know how to write the likelihood function using $\Theta$ as a vector instead of individual $\theta_i$ (now I know about multinomial distribution). Also, I don't know how to take partial derivative with the constraint that elements of $\Theta$ sum to 1.

Comment: Have you heard about [Lagrange multipliers?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Lagrange+multiplier)

Comment: I'm doing that at the moment.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.